# mesh with weights, but some vertices not work correctly

Tags: rigging

the model from DotA2 that i extract the game source file[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, if some vertices are not correctly assigned, remove them from all groups and reassign to the correct group?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.